# create a for loop to merge a dataset to its new self

Tags: r, for-loop, merge

I am trying to create a for loop that will start by merging two datasets, then iteratively merge the resulting merged dataset to another dataset. Basically, a chain of merging new datasets to the previously created merged dataset.

So far, I've written the code below, but for some reason merge.data fails to update each run through the loop, so on the last run-through it seems to merge the same merge.data from the first run it was created.

```
for(i in (length(data)-1)) {
if (i == 1) {
  merge <- data[i]
  merge1 <- data[i+1]
  merge.data <- merge(get(merge), get(merge1), all.x=TRUE)
} else {merge1 <- data[i+1]
        merge.data[i] <- merge(merge.data, get(merge1), all.x=TRUE)
}
}
```

Comment: You may need to check `Reduce(function(...) merge(...), list(data1, data2, data3))`

Comment: Without knowing structure of the list and list elements it is difficult to answer your question. Provide the data list by giving us the output of dput(data).

Comment: dput(data) = c("prb.6400.head", "prb.6400.unit", "prb.6800.head", "prb.6800.unit")

where each of those is actually a data.table. So I want to take prb.6400.head and merge it to prb.6400.unit, and in turn merge that merged dataset to prb.6800.head and finally that merged dataset to prb.6800.unit.

But I want this to be a for-loop so it can handle any number of data.table merges.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It's not elegant, but it works.

```
merge1 <- data[1]
merge2 <- data[2]
merge.data <- merge(get(merge1), get(merge2), all.x=TRUE)

for(i in 3:length(data)){ 
merge <- data[i]
merge.data <- merge(merge.data, get(merge), all.x=TRUE)
}
```